# Does AngularJS or Angular 2 provide something similar to the Redux middleware so that AJAX data appear immediately available?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, redux, angular2

I am learning React / Redux, and one feature I like is, when you fire off an Action, you actually provide a `request` as the "result" or what is called the `payload` in Redux, and the Redux middleware won't pass this Action to the reducers to compose the final application states. Instead, it will wait for the `request`, which is a promise, to resolve, and replace the `payload` with the actual response (including the data). So `payload` will finally contain the actual data, and get passed to the reducers to compose the final application states.

This way, it is almost like you can treat it as immediate data. You don't have to worry about the AJAX at all.

So if comparing this to AngularJS and Angular 2, do they provide a pattern like this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're referring to [redux-promise](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-promise), which abstracts away the work of creating your own promise-handling functionality that dispatches (or not) after the promise is done. This abstraction is easy to use because it's inserted into the redux store as middleware - in fact, the core source code of that library is [barely 25 lines of code](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-promise/blob/master/src/index.js).

Because all versions of Angular do not use a redux store by default, there's nowhere to plug in a middleware. You could, however, implement a small "scope dispatch" utility function that expects to receive promises that resolve to a certain value:

```
// Somewhere in your controller...
var buildDispatcher = function (vm) {
    var assign = function (values) {
        Object.assign(vm, values);
    };

    return function (value) {
        if (value.then) {
            return value.then(result => {
                // Here we assume that the
                // result returns an object with
                // keys and values
                return assign(result);
            });
        } else {
            assign(value);
        }
    };
};

vm.dispatch = buildDispatcher(vm);

vm.dispatch(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve({
        someKey: true
    });
}));
```

You'll notice that to get this to work as "magically" as it does in redux, we need to make sure that all values return objects whose keys are then copied over into the controller scope (I'm using Angular's ["controller as" syntax](https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/) here). Essentially, we're creating a controller-level state object with a minimal dispatch function that unpacks the return values of promises and assigns them to the scope, or if the return value doesn't have a promise-indicating `.then` method, it just assigns the value to the scope directly (but it still must be an object).

We might also have to run the `$digest` function (in Angular 1 at least - not sure about 2+) in order to get this assignment to be recognized, but I omitted that detail for clarity.